# Is Facebook Graph API v3.0 for Groups broken?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I think that Facebook has basically closed the API for groups now, and they didn't announce it.

- `user_managed_groups` has been deprecated, and it works "For testing only".
- `groups_access_member_info` returns only "member-related data on group content"
- `publish_to_groups` gives an app the ability to post content... but there is no way to retrieve the list of managed groups and `access_token`.

Is the current Groups API 3.0 broken?

P.S. There is a bug opened: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/382344108912316/

Comment: where did you read that user_managed_groups is deprecated? still works for v3.0 and there is nothing in the changelog. you always had to go through review if you wanted to go public with user_managed_groups.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v3.0

Comment: user_managed_groups
Enables your app to read the Groups a person is an admin of through the groups edge on the User object.

...
This permission is being deprecated as Groups is moving to a new permission model for apps. Please continue to use user_managed_groups for testing your apps in dev mode. However, when submitting for review, please select the reviewable feature Groups API, and do not submit this user_managed_groups in your review.

Comment: alright, now i see it. well, you can only wait for the bug report to be answered, i guess.